# Laravel Column isn't Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have a raw query. It runs pretty well in MySQL. But, it produce an error "Column X" isn't group by in Laravel.  Is there any alternative to fix this error, except disabling MySQL strict mode/set mysql strict to False? Maybe a subquery solution? Thanks in advance.

Here's the raw query

```
select ec.site_id , ec.created_at , ec.registration_number ,
        sc.document_number , sc.service_type , sc.customer_type , 
        sc.part_demand , sc.serial_number , sc.stock_in_status , 
        sc.confirm_stock_status , sc.location , sc.product_completeness , 
        sc.complaints , sc.remarks , sc.service_type , sc.warranty_type , 
        ec.part_demand , ec.serial_number , rtrd.part_demand_return , 
        rtrd.serial_number_return , sj.nik_technician , ussj.name , 
        sc.id_card_name , sc.id_card_address , sc.id_card_sub_district , 
        sc.id_card_district , sc.id_card_city , sc.id_card_province , 
        sc.owner_name , sc.owner_address , sc.owner_sub_district , 
        sc.owner_district , sc.owner_city , sc.owner_province , 
        ec.recipient_name , ec.address_visited , ec.sub_district_visited,
        ec.district_visited , ec.city_visited , ec.province_visited , 
        ec.owner_name , ec.owner_address , ec.owner_sub_district , 
        ec.owner_district , ec.owner_city , ec.owner_province , 
        sj.working_status , sc.pending_status , ec.case_status , 
        sc.status , rtr.return_nbr , rtr.created_at , rtr.return_status , 
        sum(sjd.value_after_discount + sjd.ppn_value) , sc.deposit , 
        sum(sjd.value_after_discount + sjd.ppn_value) - sc.deposit , 
        sc.confirm_deposit_status , sc.payment_status 
from external_cases ec 
    left join employees em on em.id = ec.employee_id 
    left join artemis_global.sites st on st.id = ec.site_id 
    left join service_calls sc on sc.external_case_id = ec.id 
    left join service_jobs sj on sj.service_call_id = sc.id 
    left join service_job_details sjd on sjd.service_job_id = sj.id 
    left join artemis_dev.users ussj on ussj.current_nik = sj.nik_technician 
    left join return_of_good_details rtrd on rtrd.service_calls_id = sc.id 
    left join return_of_goods rtr on rtr.id = rtrd.return_of_goods_id 
where ec.case_status <> 'CLOSED' 
and ec.case_status <> 'CANCELED' 
group by ec.registration_number, sc.document_number
```

Comment: If you can see it, just maybe you can debug it

Comment: What column is "Column X"

Comment: If it runs well in MySQL and not in Laravel it's because your MySQL mode is not strict and Laravel is strict so if you want the same results disable strict mode

Comment: @GertB. Some columns that have been selected and not in group by clause

Comment: @apokryfos Is there any solution without disabling strict mode?

Comment: You need to include all the non-aggregated columns in the group by. This should not be a problem if they are unique for the grouped column, but might alter the result if they are not. If you try to do things like wrapping the whole thing as a subquery and then grouping over it you will end up losing columns.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [select a column not in GROUP BY clause](https://tableplus.com/blog/2019/10/select-column-not-in-group-by.html) . Might be it will helpful for you.

Comment: Not my DV but this is really at best a comment